# JavaFX Replace commas(,) with dots(.) in JavaFX StringBinding

Tags: java, javafx, binding, numbers, format

> What is my goal:

I was searching a way to add (.) on large numbers in Java . After research i made the below method:

```
/**
  * @param number
  * @return A number with more than 3 digits [ Example 1000 as 1.000] with dots every 3 digits
 */
 public static String getNumberWithDots(int number) {
  return String.format(Locale.US, "%,d", number).replace(",", ".");
 }
```

> The problem:

Now i have a `Label` in JavaFX . Let's name it `label` . Actually i want to bind it's text to a `SimpleIntegerProperty` lets name it `totalCats` , but i want to format the text so it actually comforms the method above .

I mean that if the **totalCats** is **1000** , i want the label to display **1.000** . Until now i have achieved only to do **1,000** but i don't know how to replace (,) with (.) cause `StringBinding` has not a replace method :

```
label.textProperty().bind(totalCatsProperty().asString(Locale.US, "%,d"));
```

> Finally:

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bindings::create****Binding` is usefull in such cases.

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> String.format(Locale.US, "%,d", totalCatsProperty().get()).replace(",", "."),
        totalCatsProperty()));
```

Comment: O_O oou thank you catty! :) I don't think it is random that a cat answered this question !! :)